# Merge 2 flex columns into 1 alternating children

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a `flex` container with 2 columns.
Each column is also a flex container with a number of boxes inside.

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="column left-column">
    <div class="box boxA">Box A</div>
    <div class="box boxB">Box B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right-column">
    <div class="box boxC">Box C</div>
    <div class="box boxD">Box D</div>
    <div class="box boxE">Box E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that, in mobile view, the 2 columns become 1.
Right now I achieve this by adding `flex-direction: column` to the `flex-container`, which makes the 2 columns be one on top of each other (vertically, not z-axis).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 2;
}

.right-column {
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
.flex-container {
   flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

**But now I need additionally to rearrange the order of the boxes so that, in mobile view, it shows as A, C, D, E, B.**

I don't think that can be achieved with CSS alone, since it requires "breaking" the flex columns.

Here's a sandbox with what I have at the moment: https://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/ZYqjPj

Btw, this is in a React app, so I will probably have to rearrange the boxes programmatically.
I just preferred to do that with CSS, if possible.

Comment: You may want to consider using CSS Grid for this instead - you won't need the wrapping `<div>` you can simply assign the A,B,C,D,E elements to grid areas. **edit** to remove the *impossible* statement.

Comment: @disinfor Actually you *can* do this with CSS with `display: contents`.

Comment: @Paulie_D WHOA! I stand completely corrected. That's a great solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: contents` at the lower width to "break" the wrapping divs and then `order` on `.boxB`.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 2;
}

.right-column {
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column {
    display: contents;
  }
  .boxB {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="column left-column">
    <div class="box boxA">Box A</div>
    <div class="box boxB">Box B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right-column">
    <div class="box boxC">Box C</div>
    <div class="box boxD">Box D</div>
    <div class="box boxE">Box E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```